# This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows in ""

Tags: windows, qt, anaconda

On Stackoverflow this issue is already asked several times in the same or similar titles, but their cases always occurred in installing or using the Qt application.

My case is that when the Windows opened (started up), it will show the AppService message immediately as

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in"",
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

I did not know which application generating this issue, and I did not install the Qt separately, I just installed the Anaconda distribution for installing the Python, in the Anaconda I can find that it installed the package "qt-main" (Qt5), I tried to launch the Qt related applications Qt Console, JupyterLab, Jupyter Notebook, they all can run no issues.

I tried to reinstall Anaconda cleaning, the error still happened. I can ignore this issue, it seems there is no effect to the Windows usage. I do not use the Qt but I am not sure this issue if it will affect my system, because my system now often happened some troubles and the Windows Troubleshooter can not fix them, I need to reboot the PC then I can resume the system in normal situation.

I hope may fix this issue or may tell me my system issues are not related to this Qt issue, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like Anaconda bug. Help might better be found from Anaconda forums/mailing list/bugtracker/something.

Comment: I do not know about Anaconda but the windows platform plugin is simply qwindows.dll/qwindowsd.dll that you will find inside the Qt folder > plugins > platforms; usually should be placed in a platforms folder right under your **working** directory. If not that, try to see if calling  [`QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath) helps.